# build new project in wakanda in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ionic2, wakanda

I installed Wakanda in ubuntu 14.04 and the Wakanda Server is running locally with address localhost:8080

I don't know how to create a new project. It is asking me for the path to a `.waSolution` file like below:

> "Enter the absolute path to your solution's file (.waSolution) to start"

Where will I get this file to give path?

Please help me how to proceed after this and is there wakanda studio for linux OS?

Comment: Wakanda Studio is only available for Windows and OS X.

Answer (score 1):

> is there wakanda studio for linux OS?

Wakanda Studio for Linux does not exist.

There is a MacOS and Windows version of Wakanda Studio. You can install Wakanda Studio under on of these operating environments to create your Wakanda Solution to proceed.

---

> > "Enter the absolute path to your solution's file (.waSolution) to start"
>
> Where will I get this file to give path?

After you have created your solution using Wakanda Studio on MacOS or Windows you can transfer it to the Linux machine.

Take note of the location you transfer it to because this will be the location you want to use.

Answer (score 0):

Wakanda Studio help you to create a new solution and projects. To deploy on linux, you will need to have the structure of your solution/projects and run it.

You cannot create a solution on linux. [Here is the doc](http://doc.wakanda.org/home2.en.html#/Command-Line-Access/Administrating-Wakanda-Server-Unix.300-583228.en.html) for the line command tools.

Once the solution/project are created with the studio, you can use your own code editor on linux to modify you project and use it only on Linux. But then you must be aware of which files and which format and settings are needed by the server to run the project.